# Is there any shortcut to add sum of value it we have different parameters?

Tags: arraylist, collections, java-7

I have following code, in this DemoClass have getter and setter for val1, val2, val3 and val4 respectively, I want to add each value if it has more than one value in list. For example:
in first iteration val11=10000, second iteration val12=2000 and so on.Now i want a solution that result val11+val12 and this should be for each value i.e val1, val2, val3 and val4.

```
List<DemoClass> list= new ArrayList<DemoClass>();    
int count=1;
for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    DemoClass cls = (DemoClass) iterator.next();
    parameter.put("val1"+count, cls.getVal1());
    parameter.put("val2"+count, cls.getVal2());
    parameter.put("val3"+count, cls.getVal3());
    parameter.put("val4"+count, cls.getVal4());
    count++;
}
```

DemoClass.java

```
public class DemoClass{
private String val1;
private String val2;
private String val3;
private String val4;

public String getVal1() {
    return val1;
}

public void setVal1(String val1) {
    this.val1= val1;
}

public String getVal2() {
    return val2;
}

public void setVal2(String val2) {
    this.val2= val2;
}

public String getVal3() {
    return val3;
}

public void setVal3(String val3) {
    this.val3= val3;
}

public String getval4() {
    return val4;
}
public void setVal4(String val4) {
    this.val4= val4;
}
```

}

Comment: I presume that `parameter` is a map,  Can you show a complete example of what val1 thru val4 would contain and then show  what the other values contain after they are added together.  And showing a populated list with initialized classes would also be helpful.  It isn't clear to me what is going on.

Comment: @WJS the val1, val2, val3 and val4 takes input as integer and it shoud show value in the form of integer after added.

Comment: I think you want to have one DemoClass instance that have valx = sum( list.map( e=> e.valx)) (for x =1, 2, 3, and 4). is that right ?

Comment: @mohamedchadad You are right but I'm using Java 7.

Comment: @PrakashJoshi I have updated my answer (Solution for JAVA 7)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a single DemoClass **instance** that has in each value (val1, val2, val3, and val4) **the sum** of the integer value of the correspondent property in the DemoClass **list in input** this code will help if you are using `JAVA 8` or higher version `(Stream API)`

```
public static DemoClass calcul(List<DemoClass> list) {
    DemoClass demoClass = new DemoClass();
    return list.stream().reduce(demoClass, (acc, curr) -> {
        DemoClass tmp = new DemoClass();
        tmp.setVal1(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(acc.getVal1()) + Integer.parseInt(curr.getVal1())));
        tmp.setVal2(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(acc.getVal2()) + Integer.parseInt(curr.getVal2())));
        tmp.setVal3(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(acc.getVal3()) + Integer.parseInt(curr.getVal3())));
        tmp.setVal4(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(acc.getVal4()) + Integer.parseInt(curr.getVal4())));
        return tmp;
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Solution for `JAVA 7`, you need to add all arguments constructor

```
public static DemoClass calcul(List<DemoClass> list) {
    DemoClass demoClass = new DemoClass("0", "0", "0", "0");
    for(DemoClass curr : list) {
        demoClass.setVal1(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(demoClass.getVal1()) + Integer.parseInt(curr.getVal1())));
        demoClass.setVal2(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(demoClass.getVal2()) + Integer.parseInt(curr.getVal2())));
        demoClass.setVal3(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(demoClass.getVal3()) + Integer.parseInt(curr.getVal3())));
        demoClass.setVal4(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(demoClass.getVal4()) + Integer.parseInt(curr.getVal4())));
    }
    return demoClass;
}
```

**To get parameter Map:**

[image]

Comment: @mohamedchaded how can I put value in parameter which I get from this method.

Comment: @PrakashJoshi check the image that I add
I create the parameter map<String, String>, then I put forEach valx the valx value of the returned DemoClass by thee calcul method

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But in my case i have a outer loop also in which list already contains some values for val1,val2,..so on, I have to iterate though that list and adding sum each time.

Comment: @PrakashJoshi can you update your question. Add the whole code to let us know more.